# Use JavaScriptSerializer to produce object with arbitrary property names

Tags: .net, javascript, json, serialization

In .Net, I want to generate a json object as follows:

{"1":true}

Can I do so using `JavaScriptSerializer`?
Can I do it any other way?

Comment: Probably you mean `{"1":true}`, `{"1":"true"}` or `{"1":1}` because `{'1':true}` is not JSON?

Comment: I actually just need a valid javascript create-object code. But yes, I meant `{"1":true}`.

Answer (score 1):

[ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) may solve what you want.

Allows to build object with dynamic properties but compatible only with .net 4